# Live Output From Process Windows 7 vs Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, process, command-line-interface

I am writing an application that calls an external process via the command line.  I have coded the external process to not show a command window, but display the output of the external process in a rich text box in another form.  This code works on Windows 7.  However when I move the application to a Windows 10 machine the command window is visible and the output of the process does not show in my rich text box.  Debugging the application on Windows 10 shows that the DeviceReceivedEventHandler is not being triggered.  Can anyone explain why this is different between the Operating Systems and how I might be able to fix it?

Here is the method that I am having issues with:

```
        private void commandLineProcess(string cmdArgs)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = process.StartInfo;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.Arguments = cmdArgs;

        if (!cmdArgs.Contains("FindDrive"))
        {
            Form progress = new Forms.mForceWriteProgress();
            progress.Show();

            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                {
                    Forms.mForceWriteProgress.Instance.addToRichTextBox(e.Data);
                }
            });
        }

        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Any errors in your Event Log?

Comment: maybe permission issue

Comment: do you have `/c` in your cmdArgs? It looks like the cmd processor on Win7 might not have cared about that but the Win 10 one does.

Comment: This works fine for me on WIndows 10. Can you give the details of what cmdArgs you are passing in that gives the issue.

Comment: Why are you running this via cmd.exe instead of directly? You only need to use a command-line shell for a complex command line that sets up standard I/O redirection and piping, or uses internal CMD commands and environment variables, or maybe if you need to use `cmd /k` to keep the shell attached to the console after the program exits. But normally if you're just running a single executable, there is no reason at all to use CMD. It only complicates handling the command line and compromises security.

Comment: I did have the /C in the cmdArgs.  I have not figured out what the difference is and I have decided with a new approach.  Instead of redirecting the output I am just letting the application display it's output in the console.  This allows me to finish up the other parts of the application and I will look at this again for the next release.